# How to issue commands from inside a loop?

Tags: tcl

This is a very basic question.
I think of TCL as a command line generator.  Its purpose is to generate strings for the tool’s command line interpreter.  For example, the tcl commands:

```
set alpha “run”
$alpha
$alpha
$alpha
```

cause the “run” command to be sent to the tool three times – which makes sense.  But:

```
set alpha “run”
for {set i 0} {$i<3} {incr i} $alpha
```

does not. So the question is: How do I send commands to the tool from inside a loop?

Comment: Style point: write the loop as `for {set i 0} {$i<3} {incr i} {$alpha}` to avoid possible issues with quoting. I hope that's not going to fix it for real for you, but maybe…

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely to be with the "funny quotes" in the line

```
set alpha “run”
```

To Tcl, those quotes aren't syntactic markers, just text. Try

```
set alpha "run"
```

or, even better,

```
set alpha run
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way (with output):

```
% proc foo {count} {
    puts "count = $count"
}
% set alpha foo
foo
% for {set i 0} {$i<3} {incr i} {
    $alpha $i    
}
count = 0
count = 1
count = 2
%
```

Comment: The use of eval is unnecessary here and can actually break things if any of the arguments has list structure.

Comment: @PeterLewerin Agree. Thanks. Updated the snippet above.